# Calling a table within a PHP parameter

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I know it has something to do with the parameter, on my HTML page I'm trying to do an automate next button, so let's say I have the first episode of a series, anime, or whatever, so first of all the episodes will come from a dashboard I've created using the id as parameter, so they will all come as example.com/episode.php? id=1 in order to make the HTML receive all the replazables variables I use this call

```
<?php
// Check existence of id parameter before processing further
if(isset($_GET["id"]) && !empty(trim($_GET["id"]))){
    // Include config file
    include_once "config.php";
    
    // Prepare a select statement
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM testEpisode WHERE id = ?";
    
    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql)){
        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $param_id);
        
        // Set parameters
        $param_id = trim($_GET["id"]);
        
        // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
            $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){
                /* Fetch result row as an associative array. Since the result set contains only one row, we don't need to use while loop */
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                
                
                // Retrieve individual field value
                $name = $row["name"];
                $episode = $row["episode"];
                $video1 = $row["video1"];
                $video2 = $row["video2"];
            }
        } else{
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
        }
    }
     
    // Close statement
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    
    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($conn);
} 

?>
```

So that gives the URL and the episode with all the variables I already entered, but here s the thing somewhere on the HTML I want to create a next button, let me try to recreate this since I already tested it all alone and it works, my main idea to create the next button was to

```
<?php
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM testEpisode ORDER by id desc limit 1';
if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     $x = $row['id'];   
 }
}
```

The main idea was if the id of this page is equal to the last id entered on the table then execute this

```
if($row['id'] == $x){
      $a=no;

}else{
      $a=yes;
      $b = $row['id'] + 1;
}

echo '<div class="' . $a . '">';       
        
echo '<a id="link"  href="read.php?id=' . $b . '">';

echo '<i class="fas fa-caret-right" style="font-size:30px;color:white"></i><p class="letter"> Next</p></a>';

echo '</div>';
```

It seems because of the parameter I'm getting on my id, I'm not able to get the last id on that table, I've tried a LOT of things, and it's either the main id of that HTML or the last id, it won't let me print both, any idea how to do this?

Comment: Seems like your saying `$x = $row['id'];` then `if($row['id'] == $x)`, and if so that always returns true.

Comment: Could you clarify yourself a bit more?

Comment: sure, how can i get the last inserted id? since im already on one of the page that have an id lets say episode.php?id=1 (because it has all the variables of the database) once im on that page it wont let me get the last inserted id